# List all active methods in jshell

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

is there any command available that can print all newly created methods in current jshell session? 
Something similar to `/list` but only for methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the command

```
/methods -all
```

which prints all the methods including those added when JShell was started, and methods that failed, were overwritten, or were dropped.

For active methods declared by you, use it simply without any argument as :

```
/methods
```